# Unterminated String Literal error with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm developing a web app to look for friends,and it uses the game's api,here's the actual code:
http://pastebin.com/NmDaXdjB
And there's an error in the line 20,"unterminated string literal".
What is it?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Change from `'</div>);` to `'</div>');`

Comment: Believe it or not, you have a string literal, on line 20, that you haven’t terminated.

Comment: I did,but the error still there...

Comment: @user2570025 cant be the same error, on what line is it now?

Comment: Same error.Actually,the "'</div>);" mistake was just a copy&paste mistake,the original code was fixed.The error still in the same place and line,line 20.

Comment: @user2570025: could you show us on http://www.jsfiddle.net/? Code actually runs there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite could it be that `nomeserver` is undefined?

Comment: @InGodITrust: I think you’re right that `nomeserver` would be undefined when `'</h2>' + nomeserver + '</div>'` runs, but I don’t think that would give an unterminated string literal error.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yeah, thats what I thought as well, just decided to run it through with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing a final single quote here:

```
data['playerInfo']['username'] + '</h2>' + nomeserver + '</div>);
```

Change to:

```
data['playerInfo']['username'] + '</h2>' + nomeserver + '</div>');
```

Comment: You missed it... if you see your code highlight, it's easily spotted.

Comment: @gdoron what was that?

Comment: Technically it’s a prime symbol, although it’s often used as an apostrophe. Not technically a speech mark though.

Comment: I did it,but the error stills there.

Comment: O.K. now you fixed it.

Comment: But the error stills there...

Comment: @gdoron not sure what you referring to, only thing i edited was to remove the unneeded part of the string!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite didnt have the time to start searching for the right term ;)

Comment: The original code was with '</div>'); ,i just did a mistake when I copied it.

Comment: @InGodITrust: :) *No time, damnit!*

Comment: @user2570025: then you wouldn’t have had the “unterminated string literal” error.

Comment: I still have the same error.THE ERROR IS NOT IN "'</div>);".It's fixed already.

Comment: @user2570025 on what line

Comment: Line 20.As I said,is the same error.

Comment: @user2570025 doesnt make sense that error still exists, btw swap `nomeserver` for a `something` and see if that works.

Comment: @user2570025: I’ve copied the code from your pastebin into an HTML page, created a global object `data` with adequate properties for the code to run, and I’m not seeing that error.

Comment: But there is that error.It should append a piece of code to the html,but it isn't.And the error that the code editor shows to me is that : "Unterminated string literal".

Comment: @user2570025 did you try swapping the word `nomeserver` for a random string like `'anything'`

Comment: I just tried it.It didin't fix.Same result.

Comment: @user2570025 no idea then, doesnt make sense. Try it incognito browser, maybe the old one is cached!

Comment: @user2570025: Oh, there is that error? Well, that’s different then — I’ll start imagining what could be causing it. Or you could post a working example that demonstrates the error on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I can't,it needs a HTML + CSS file,jsfiddle doesn't allow you to config the head of the HTML.

Comment: @user2570025 ask a new question with clearer details then, and we'll take another look.

Comment: @user2570025: you don’t have to put in any CSS on JS Fiddle, and scripts work just the same in `<body>` and they do in `<head>`.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite very creative ;)

Comment: I don't know how to do it @PaulD.Waite . I'll do a new question.

Comment: @user2570025 before you do that, his suggestion is good. Copy the end of the code from my answer and replace yours. Then check again! Users wont like another question so exhaust all options first!

Comment: I already did that .Like 20 times. Here's the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633798/unterminated-string-literal-error-in-jquery

Comment: @LucasT.: with respect, if you can’t figure out how to create an example on JS Fiddle, you’re going to have a lot of trouble getting your gamer signature app written.

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea idea to split up your code.

The div as a template:

```
var nomeserver = 'whatever',
    username = data['playerInfo']['username']
    memberHTMLTpl = '<div id=\"member\" class=\"large-11 columns\">'
                       + '<h2>'
                           + username
                       + '<h2>'
                    + nomeserver
                    + '</div>';

$('#members').append(memberHTMLTpl);
```